# Sourcing one data function within another data function in the same library in Spotfire

Tags: r, spotfire, terr

I have written two Data Functions in Spotfire as R script Type. One Data Function sources the functions from another Data Function, say "FunctionName.R," in R as:

```
source("C:\\Users\\Username\\FunctionName.R")
```

However, I need to reference the same FunctionName.R from the other Data Function in the Spotfire library rather than on the C: drive. It should look something like:

```
source("\\MainLibrary\\SubLibrary\\FunctionName.R")
```

where "/MainLibrary/SubLibrary/FunctionName.R" is the Path shown in Data Function Properties. But that path did not work with the source command.

How can I source from the Path shown in Data Function Properties from the same library rather than my local drive?

Answer (score 4):

A quick hack is to first open up the Main Library FunctionName.R file in RStudio, then go to session --> set working directory --> to source file location. Then you'll know the exact file path. Sometimes this is a simple fix.

Essentially, the error you're receiving seems to indicate that either the file you're pointing to does not exist or you are providing `source` with an incorrect path. Without knowing your OS, R version, etc, the best way is the easiest way. Have a look [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200629668-RStudio-source-command-not-working) for more information.

Comment: Using "source" with a file on your local machine is easy, and I have gotten this to work. The problem here is referencing a file on the server. I have not seen an example where "source" will work with a server path, and TIBCO also did not suggest this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I received from TIBCO is to create a custom package for any functions that should not be included in the main Data Function and import the package into Spotfire.